# writing custom membership provider

Tags: c#, .net, membership-provider, sqlmembershipprovider

i am writing the custom membership provider class by implementing System.Web.Security.membershipprovider.

now my problem is while accessing the class i am getting error as

error code :

```
String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: s
```

Stack trace:

```
   at System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(String s)
   at ss.Provider.EncodePassword(String password) 
   at ss.Provider.CreateUser(String username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey, MembershipCreateStatus& status) 
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.AttemptCreateUser()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.OnNextButtonClick(WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.WizardChildTable.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

and my class as

create user:

```
 public override MembershipUser GetUser(object userID,bool userIsOnline)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("User_SelByUserID", sqlConnection);

            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@userID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = userID;

            MembershipUser membershipUser = null;
            SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = null;

            try
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();

                sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                if (sqlDataReader.HasRows)
                {
                    sqlDataReader.Read();
                    membershipUser = GetUserFromReader(sqlDataReader);

                    if (userIsOnline)
                    {
                        SqlCommand sqlUpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("User_UpdateActivityDate_ByUserID", sqlConnection);

                        sqlUpdateCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        sqlUpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@userID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = userID;
                        sqlUpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@applicationName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = applicationName;
                        sqlUpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                //Add exception handling here.
            }
            finally
            {
                if (sqlDataReader != null) { sqlDataReader.Close(); }
            }

            return membershipUser;

        }
```

Encode password:

```
private string EncodePassword(string password)
        {
            string encodedPassword = password;

            switch (PasswordFormat)
            {
                case MembershipPasswordFormat.Clear:
                    break;
                case MembershipPasswordFormat.Encrypted:
                    encodedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptPassword(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password)));
                    break;
                case MembershipPasswordFormat.Hashed:
                    HMACSHA1 hash = new HMACSHA1();
                    hash.Key = HexToByte(machineKey.ValidationKey);
                    encodedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password)));
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ProviderException("Unsupported password format.");
            }

            return encodedPassword;
        }
```

the password given string is Gowtham!1

Updated:

```
  public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
        {

            ValidatePasswordEventArgs args = new ValidatePasswordEventArgs(username, password, true);

            OnValidatingPassword(args);

            if (args.Cancel)
            {
                status = MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword;
                return null;
            }

            if ((RequiresUniqueEmail && (GetUserNameByEmail(email) != String.Empty)))
            {
                status = MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail;
                return null;
            }

            MembershipUser membershipUser = GetUser(username, false);

            if (membershipUser == null)
            {
                System.DateTime createDate = DateTime.Now;

                SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("User_Ins", sqlConnection);

                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@returnValue", SqlDbType.Int, 0).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = username; ;
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@applicationName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = applicationName;
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = EncodePassword(password);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = email;
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@passwordQuestion", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = passwordQuestion;
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@passwordAnswer", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = EncodePassword(passwordAnswer);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@isApproved", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = isApproved;
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@comment", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = String.Empty;

                try
                {
                    sqlConnection.Open();

                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if ((int)sqlCommand.Parameters["@returnValue"].Value == 0)
                    {

                        status = MembershipCreateStatus.Success;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        status = MembershipCreateStatus.UserRejected;
                    }
                }
                catch (SqlException e)
                {
                    //Add exception handling here.

                    status = MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError;
                }
                finally
                {
                    sqlConnection.Close();
                }

                return GetUser(username, false);
            }
            else
            {
                status = MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You've included the wrong code, you've included the `GetUser` method instead of the `CreateUser` one.

Comment: Use breakpoints to step through your code until you get the error then post the details here.

Comment: @all thanks for responses will post now?

Comment: @mattmanser while creating the user i get error as String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: s

Comment: The problem is in your stored procedure, can you post/add the sp?

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick i do not have OnValidatingPassword method are you asking any other thing

Comment: Are you passing the password at all, have you tried to debug CreateUser and see if the password is null?

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick ya i ma getting password string the value i entered

Comment: I think that CreateUser doesn't even get the string for password but null instead.

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick this are my entire code shrib.com/SoCAaw2j

Comment: As far as I can see from your code, it's fine, the problem is when CreateUserWizard is trying to create new user, you somehow don't set its password property, it stays null and you get the exception. Check if you set the password.

Answer (score 0):

A guess, but my bet is that it's not the `password` variable, it's because you're trying to encode `passwordAnswer` which you're not passing in, or passing a null value in. You're probably not using this functionality, which is an out of date and dangerous way of recovering passwords that MS haven't deprecated.

This line in `CreateUser`:

```
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@passwordAnswer", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = EncodePassword(passwordAnswer);  \\THIS LINE IS PROBABLY THE PROBLEM
```

Try this instead, but only if you're definitely not using this functionality:

```
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@passwordAnswer", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = passwordAnswer;
```

You should be able to check this easily in debugging.

Answer (score -1):

Use the debugger to find out what happened.

If you don't know how to do that, then, add this line:

```
if(password == null)
    throw new Exception("Password is null here, I get it, now I'll try to find where is wrong!");
```

before this line in your CreateUser method:

```
ValidatePasswordEventArgs args = new ValidatePasswordEventArgs(username, password, true);
```

And run again, see if anything happens.

Comment: error code as {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Could not find stored procedure 'User_Sel'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError

Comment: Then check the stored procedure, to make sure it is there in the database. And make sure you have connected the right database.

Comment: in which derived class i can change the database name

Comment: Wait a minute, I see this `SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);` what's `connectString`? Check where it is defined, and how it's assigned, and you'll know how to change the database.

Comment: i am reading and setting connection string as   ConnectionStringSettings ConnectionStringSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[config["connectionStringName"]];

            if ((ConnectionStringSettings == null) || (ConnectionStringSettings.ConnectionString.Trim() == String.Empty))
            {
                throw new ProviderException("Connection string cannot be blank.");
            }

            connectionString = ConnectionStringSettings.ConnectionString;

Comment: Then check your web.config file. should be under the <connectionStrings> section.

Comment: my webconfig file is <membership defaultProvider="tMembershipProvider">
   <providers>
    <add name="MembershipProvider" type="MembershipProvider,com.corenttech.mts.membership" connectionStringName="SQLMembershipConnString" applicationName=".NET Pet Shop 4.0" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed"  />
   </providers>     
  </membership>

Comment: connectionString="server=******; database=****;user id=**;password=****;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: Does that points to the right database? If this doesn't resolve your promblem, try learning to use the debugger.